# How to draw image from SVG path points through canvas in android and set image inside the drawn shape

Tags: java, android, svg, android-canvas

i want to draw shape threw SVG path point. i am able to get path points from SVG image but i am not able to draw it through canvas.
if any body has any idea how to do it please help me.
i am stuck at it.

Comment: Maybe this lib can help you some way - https://github.com/devendroid/VectorChildFinder

Comment: So you want to draw an image inside an SVG path on Android?  Why not just draw use an SVG library such as AndroidSVG (my one)?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau can your library fulfill my need ?

Comment: I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise.  But it depends what you mean by "i want to draw shape". Do you mean "I want to have an SVG shape with an image as the fill".  If so then yes. my library supports all the features you will need.  But if you mean "draw the shape at at run time", then that is a little more complicated.